# Implementing exceptions into atm project

Tags: java, exception, bank

I have an assignment to create a little banking program that keeps two accounts, regular and savings. However, as I was about to finish a rough version, I read on the prompt that I was suppose to use what we learned about the day I was sick, exceptions.

I'm not to clear on how to use exception or if I should make my own exception class. I want an exception so that at any point in the program if something that starts with 'q' or 'Q' is entered the program quits and end. Another stipulation was that if the savings went below 25$ to freeze the account. I imagine exceptions would be ideal for that functionality.

```
public abstract class BankAccount {

    int balance;
    int deposits;
    int withdrawals;
    int annualInterestRate;
    int charges;

    public void _BankAccount(int newBalance, int newInterest) {
        balance = newBalance;
        annualInterestRate = newInterest;
    }

    public void Deposit(int newDeposit) {
        balance = balance + newDeposit;
        deposits++;
    }

    public void Withdraw(int newWithdraw) {
        balance = balance - newWithdraw;
        withdrawals++;
    }

    public void calcInterest() {
        int monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate / 12);
        int monthlyInterest = balance * monthlyInterestRate;
        balance = balance + monthlyInterest;
    }

    public void monthlyProcess() {
        balance = balance - charges;
        calcInterest();
        deposits = 0;
        withdrawals = 0;
    }
}

public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

    boolean status;

    public void savingWithdraw(int newWithdraw) {
        if (balance < 25) {
            System.out.println("Error – Not enough funds.");
        } else {
            Withdraw(newWithdraw);
        }
    }

    public void savingDeposit(int newDeposit) {
        if (balance < 25) {
            Deposit(newDeposit);
            System.out.println("Savings account is now active.");
        } else {
            Deposit(newDeposit);
        }
    }

    public void savingMonthlyProcess() {
        if (withdrawals > 4) {
            charges = ((withdrawals - 4) * 1);
            balance = balance - ((withdrawals - 4) * 1);
            if (balance < 25) {
                System.out.println("Savings account is now inactive.");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice;
    int num = 0;
    boolean quit = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Which account would you like to access, regular or savings?:");
        choice = in.nextLine();
        if (choice.equals("regular")) {
            num = 0;
        }
        if (choice.equals("savings")) {
            num = 1;
        }
        switch (num) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("What action do you wish to perform \n(Withdraw, deposit, monthly processing)?:");
                choice = in.nextLine();
                if (choice.equals("withdraw")) {
                    num = 0;
                }
                if (choice.equals("deposit")) {
                    num = 1;
                }
                if (choice.equals("monthly processing")) {
                    num = 2;
                }
                switch (num) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw:");
                        Withdraw(in.nextInt());
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw:");
                        Deposit(in.nextInt());
                    case 2:
                        MonthlyProcess();
                }
            case 1:
                System.out.println("What action do you wish to perform \n(Withdraw, deposit, monthly processing)?:");
                choice = in.nextLine();
                if (choice.equals("withdraw")) {
                    num = 0;
                }
                if (choice.equals("deposit")) {
                    num = 1;
                }
                if (choice.equals("monthly processing")) {
                    num = 2;
                }
                switch (num) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw:");
                        savingsWithdraw(in.nextInt());
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw:");
                        savingsDeposit(in.nextInt());
                    case 2:
                        savingMonthlyProcess();
                }

        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: `" I want an exception so that at any point in the program if something that starts with 'q' or 'Q' is entered the program quits and end."` -- I'm not sure I'd use an exception for this behavior. Instead, I'd use an exception if the user enters a non-numeric input where a number is expected, or if the user tries to withdraw more than the account holds.

Comment: Exceptions are generally reserved for irregular, non-standard behavior.  If pushing `Q` is the intended method for quitting the program, then it shouldn't be handled via exception.  You should handle exceptions for things like entering `$34aby53` as a deposit amount, etc. Or for sending negative values to `Deposit` and `Withdraw` methods, as a `-$25` deposit should instead be a `$25` withdraw, etc.

Comment: You need to add **break;** to your switch - case statement first. and go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are used to handle situations that are not desired. In your case, you can use the inbuilt exception classes to handle most of the run-time exceptions, but with custom messages.

> Another stipulation was that if the savings went below 25$ to freeze the account.

For the above condition, you can very well create a new exception class and handle this exception with a user-defined error message.

You can read more information on [Exception handling in java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm).